How to implement text highlighting in a console text editor C#
I create an application similar to vim, a small console text editor. And I have a problem with the implementation of text highlighting.
I know that there are two ways to write this, either using regular expressions or using an abstract syntax tree. I don't want to use regular expressions because it doesn't give enough information. I used a tokenizer and divided my text into tokens and gave each one a type, but this information is not enough (I also need the position of the token relative to the others to determine whether the set of characters is a function or class assignment).
How can I create this abstract syntax tree and, most importantly, how can I use it to highlight the text?
I want to be able to (speaking of HTML) highlight the tag name in color 1, the parametric label name in color 2, the quotation marks in color 3, the equals sign in color 4, and so on.
Maybe there is another way to do this without using an abstract syntax tree.
If possible, provide a piece of code that will implement this logic, for example, for html or css.
This is a piece of tokenizer code
public enum HTMLTokenType
{
    End,
    Quotes,
    Equal,
    String,
    Close,
    Open,
}

public class Token
{
    public Token(HTMLTokenType type, int start, int length)
    {
        Type = type;
        Start = start;
        Length = length;
    }

    public HTMLTokenType Type { get; set; }
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
}

public class HTMLLexer
{
    private readonly string _text;
    private int _cursor;

    private readonly Dictionary<string, (HTMLTokenType, int)> _keywords = new()
    {
        { "<", (HTMLTokenType.Open, "<".Length) },
        { "</", (HTMLTokenType.Open, "</".Length) },
        { "/>", (HTMLTokenType.Close, "/>".Length) },
        { ">", (HTMLTokenType.Close, ">".Length) },
        { "=", (HTMLTokenType.Equal, "=".Length) },
        { "\"", (HTMLTokenType.Quotes, "\"".Length) },
    };

    public HTMLLexer(string text)
    {
        _text = text;
    }

    public Token NextToken()
    {
        if (_cursor >= _text.Length)
        {
            return new Token(HTMLTokenType.End, _cursor, 0);
        }

        if (_cursor + 1 < _text.Length && _keywords.ContainsKey(_text[_cursor..(_cursor + 2)]))
        {
            (HTMLTokenType type, int length) = _keywords[_text[_cursor..(_cursor + 2)].ToString()];
            Token token = new(type, _cursor, length);
            _cursor += length;
            return token;
        }


        if (_keywords.ContainsKey(_text[_cursor].ToString()))
        {
            (HTMLTokenType type, int length) = _keywords[_text[_cursor].ToString()];
            Token token = new(type, _cursor, length);
            _cursor += length;
            return token;
        }

        string @string = "";
        while (_cursor < _text.Length)
        {
            if (_text[_cursor] == ' ')
            {
                Token token = new(HTMLTokenType.String, _cursor - @string.Length, @string.Length);
                _cursor++;
                return token;
            }
            if (_keywords.ContainsKey(_text[_cursor].ToString()) || (_cursor + 1 < _text.Length && _keywords.ContainsKey(_text[_cursor..(_cursor + 2)])))
            {
                return new Token(HTMLTokenType.String, _cursor - @string.Length, @string.Length);
            }

            @string += _text[_cursor].ToString();
            _cursor++;
        }

        return new Token(HTMLTokenType.End, _cursor, 0);
    }
}


Maybe it's easier to use an already existing solution (even though if it's not managed code so you need to use P/Invoke), which is also used in console applications such as the syntax highlighter plugin of Far Manager.

"I used a tokenizer...", and then ""How can I create this abstract syntax tree" -- tokenizer gives you a stream of tokens. In order to get AST you need to execute parser as well. I wouldn't write tokenizer/parser manually but use general purpose parser library for it, or even better some existing HTML parser.

Writing a syntax parser is meta-djin thinking and the ultimate case of Hofstadter's law, especially for HTML :)
Here's a few pointers, having wrote both token-based and regex-based parsers (and syntax declaration parsers) in different languages and stacks (say desktop vs. web/cloud).

You're writing a state machine regardless of your parsing preference, and even before the user presses another key, never mind copying & pasting blocks of code. That means you need strategies for current state (at rest) and for each event or type of event.
Regex-pattern (pun intended) does get you into performance considerations as explained in Interpreted vs. source-generated vs. compiled regular expressions. The learning curve is steeper, but patterns achieve greater encapsulation in syntax rules (another object in your model).
The token-based approach is for single-character tokens (ahem, tokens). It is fast, but it multiplies states sensibly and makes it harder to express and/or interpret syntax rules.
Don't append to a string, use a string builder instead.
The state machine is a giant switch onion that layers spans with styles, say, if '<' push a tag span to the stack at that position, if '=' push the equal span and if '>' close the span, and so on. This is faster than traversing your dictionary keys.
There's quite a few open-source highlighters out there; do reinvent the wheel if you aim to learn, do not if you have a timeline and a paycheck associated to this :). The ultimate C# full blown code base is Avalon Edit, and I've written extensively about a simple HTML/JS/CSS OOP approach (with working samples) at github/hectorjrivas/syntaxhighlighting.

